# How to visually represent lists in Flutter?

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart, sorting

I've been trying to build a sorting visualizer in Flutter but how do I represent the list of integers to be sorted as 'bars' on screen. Do you guys know any widgets/classes that would help me achieve the same?

Answer (score 3):

Check this widgets:
`ListView` or `ListView.builder`
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html  (there is a good YT video expalining it)
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html